# Why does my merge list algorithm not work

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this question from [here]: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //dummyhead doesn't store anything useful
        ListNode dummyhead = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode curr = dummyhead.next;
        while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if(l1.val < l2.val) {
                //System.out.println("!!!");
                curr = l1;
                curr = curr.next;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                curr = l2;
                //System.out.println(curr.val);
                System.out.println(dummyhead.next);
                curr = curr.next;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
        }
        return dummyhead.next;    
    }
}
```

I'd expect it to have the correct output of the merged list. But it is returning an empty list. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are doing all your assignments on `curr`, which will never change the value of `dummyhead.next`.

Comment: you return the last node(tail) of your constucted list instead of the first.

Answer (score 0):

`ListNode curr = dummyhead.next;` Here dummyhead.next is null coz its not pointing to an object which makes curr also null.

`curr = l1;` By doing this, curr which pointed to null now points to l1. Nowhere here does the dummyhead.next ever get set.

So you could instead do

```
ListNode curr = dummyhead;
    while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if(l1.val < l2.val) {
            //System.out.println("!!!");
            curr.next = l1;
            curr = curr .next;
            l1 = l1.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable with name curr, and it initiates with next value of dummyhead, which is null. Then you assign it a new value, but it doesn't make any effect with dummyhead structure. Obviously the result will be an empty list, because you don't do any operation with structure dummyhead.
Your task (it is a study task at all) is to keep in touch the initial structure with cursor.

It usually helps to draw a picture, how structures points to each other, to sort out how the result would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea is right, however there are some problems with your algorithm.

You are moving head twice when you are doing

```
    // Set current pointer to l1
    curr = l1;
    // Now curr == l1, both l1 and curr are pointing to the same object,
    // you are changing refence to the l1.next, so you have just missed l1 value
    curr = curr.next;
    // Change to one more element further, so in result your are moving twice
    l1 = l1.next;
```

So instead  you need to assign value and then move further

Also you will get one of the lists pointers set to `NULL` while another will have items left, in that case it will have only one item left.

Considering this case you need to add remaining items, depending which pointer will be set to null `l1` or `l2`. Only one of lists will still have items because another will be set to null by the previous `while` loop.

Here is a modified version of your algorithm.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Init first list 
        ListNode firstList = new ListNode(new ListNode(new ListNode(null,4),2),1);
        ListNode secondList =new ListNode(new ListNode(new ListNode(null,4),3),1);
        ListNode mergedList = mergeTwoLists(firstList,secondList);
        while(mergedList !=null) {
            System.out.println(mergedList.val);
            mergedList = mergedList.next;
        }
    }
    public static class ListNode {
        public ListNode next;
        public int val;
        public ListNode(ListNode next,int val) {
            this.next = next;
            this.val = val;
        }
        public ListNode() {

        }
    }
    public static ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //dummyhead doesn't store anything useful
        ListNode dummyhead = new ListNode();
        ListNode curr = dummyhead;
        while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if(l1.val < l2.val) {
                curr.next = l1;
                curr = curr.next;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                curr.next = l2;
                curr = curr.next;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
        }
        // Add remaining items from first list
        while(l1 !=null) {
            curr.next = l1;
            curr = curr.next;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        // Add remaining items from second list
        while(l2 !=null) {
            curr.next = l2;
            curr = curr.next;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        return dummyhead.next;    
    }
}
```

Of course it can be optimized and refactored, however for better understanding I modified it as above.